# Run a bash command in electron js and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron

I'm trying to run a bash command inside React/Electron, but I keep getting the error:

```
(0 , child_process__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.spawn) is not a function
```

Here's my current code for the component:

```js
import React from "react";

import TEXSymbol from "./Symbols/TEX";
import PDFSymbol from "./Symbols/PDF";

import { spawn } from "child_process";

type NoteProp = {
  data?: {
    name: string;
    tex_path: string;
    pdf_path: string;
    tex: boolean;
    pdf: boolean;
  }[];
};

function openPDF(path: string): void {
  const child = spawn("zathura", [path]);

  child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  child.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  child.on("close", (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
};

const openTEX = () => {
  console.log("Button clicked!");
};

const Note: React.FC<NoteProp> = ({ data }) => {
  if (!data) {
    return (
      <div style={{ color: "#9E9C9E" }}>No Lecture Notes</div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ lineHeight: 2.5 }}>
      <div style={{ fontSize: "17px", color: "#9E9C9E" }}>
        Lecture Notes
      </div>

      <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((note) => (
            <tr key={note.name}>
              <td>{note.name}</td>
              <td style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
                <span>
                  {note.pdf &&
                    <span
                      style={{
                        paddingRight: (note.pdf && note.tex) ? "10px" : "0px",
                        verticalAlign: "middle"
                      }}>
                      <PDFSymbol onClick={() => openPDF(note.pdf_path)} />
                    </span>}
                  {note.tex &&
                    <span style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}>
                      <TEXSymbol onClick={openTEX} />
                    </span>}
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Note;
```

And here's the code for the `PDFSymbol`:

```js
import React from "react";

type PDFSymbolProps = {
  className?: string,
  onClick: () => void,
};

const PDFSymbol: React.FC<PDFSymbolProps> = ({ className, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className} style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
      <svg className="pdf-button" onClick={onClick} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={32} height={32}>
        <path
          d="M23.734 20.879c-.39.113-.96.125-1.574.035a7.565 7.565 0 0 1-1.992-.59c1.176-.172 2.09-.12 2.871.156.188.067.492.243.695.399Zm-6.57-1.082c-.047.012-.094.023-.14.039-.317.086-.626.168-.922.246l-.403.102c-.804.203-1.629.41-2.445.66.312-.746.598-1.5.879-2.239a95.82 95.82 0 0 1 .64-1.652c.114.184.23.367.352.55.55.845 1.246 1.622 2.04 2.294Zm-2.05-8.41c.054.918-.145 1.804-.438 2.656-.36-1.05-.524-2.211-.078-3.148.117-.239.21-.368.273-.434.094.144.219.469.242.926Zm-4.208 11.656c-.199.363-.406.7-.617 1.02-.508.765-1.344 1.585-1.77 1.585-.042 0-.093-.003-.167-.085-.047-.047-.055-.086-.051-.133.011-.282.386-.785.926-1.25a9.365 9.365 0 0 1 1.68-1.137Zm14.192-2.125c-.067-.941-1.649-1.543-1.664-1.547-.61-.219-1.274-.324-2.032-.324-.804 0-1.675.117-2.797.379a9.731 9.731 0 0 1-2.496-2.567c-.285-.433-.539-.863-.761-1.285.543-1.297 1.03-2.691.941-4.258-.07-1.25-.637-2.093-1.402-2.093-.528 0-.98.39-1.352 1.164-.656 1.37-.484 3.129.516 5.226-.36.848-.696 1.723-1.02 2.57-.402 1.055-.816 2.145-1.285 3.18-1.312.52-2.39 1.149-3.285 1.922-.59.504-1.3 1.277-1.34 2.082-.02.383.11.73.375 1.008.281.297.633.453 1.024.453 1.28 0 2.515-1.762 2.75-2.117.472-.707.914-1.5 1.343-2.414 1.09-.395 2.25-.688 3.375-.973l.403-.101c.304-.078.617-.16.941-.25.34-.094.691-.188 1.047-.282 1.156.735 2.398 1.215 3.61 1.391 1.019.148 1.925.063 2.538-.258.551-.285.582-.73.57-.906Zm2.484 8.078c0 1.719-1.52 1.824-1.824 1.828H6.195c-1.715 0-1.816-1.527-1.82-1.828V3.004c0-1.723 1.52-1.824 1.82-1.828H19.41l.008.008V6.34c0 1.035.625 2.992 2.996 2.992h5.121l.047.047Zm-1.215-20.84h-3.953c-1.715 0-1.816-1.515-1.82-1.816V2.363Zm2.387 20.84V8.891L20.594.695V.66h-.04L19.899 0H6.195C5.16 0 3.2.629 3.2 3.004v25.992c0 1.04.63 3.004 2.996 3.004h19.567c1.035 0 2.992-.629 2.992-3.004Zm0 0"
          style={{
            stroke: "none",
            fillRule: "nonzero",
            fill: "#eb5757",
            fillOpacity: 1,
          }}
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PDFSymbol;
```

`TEXSymbol` component:

```js
import React from "react";

type TEXSymbolProps = {
  className?: string,
  onClick: () => void,
};

const TEXSymbol: React.FC<TEXSymbolProps> = ({ className, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className} style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
      <svg className="tex-button" onClick={onClick} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width={40} height={40}>
        <path
          d="M14.168 16.402c-.16-1.953-.305-3.445-2.86-3.445H9.888v10.5h2.683v.766l-3.855-.04-3.852.04v-.766h2.68v-10.5H6.105c-2.558 0-2.699 1.512-2.859 3.445H2.5l.355-4.207H14.56l.355 4.207h-.75Zm0 0"
          style={{
            stroke: "none",
            fillRule: "nonzero",
            fill: "#000",
            fillOpacity: 1,
          }}
        />
        <path
          d="M24.11 28.164H13.011v-.766h1.883V16.832h-1.883v-.762h10.797l.515 4.207h-.75c-.265-2.289-.851-3.445-3.57-3.445h-2.766V21.5h1.047c1.707 0 1.883-.75 1.883-2.078h.75v4.918h-.75c0-1.348-.18-2.074-1.883-2.074h-1.047v5.129h2.77c3.09 0 3.75-1.383 4.125-4.032h.75Zm0 0"
          style={{
            stroke: "none",
            fillRule: "nonzero",
            fill: "#000",
            fillOpacity: 1,
          }}
        />
        <path
          d="M34.66 23.984c-.676 0-2.453 0-3.02.036v-.77h1.473l-3.195-4.441-3.16 4.226c.523.16 1.07.23 1.617.215v.766c-.445-.04-1.969-.04-2.52-.04-.5 0-1.937 0-2.343.04v-.766h.476a9.12 9.12 0 0 0 1.032-.055c.625-.054.675-.105.832-.32l3.57-4.75-3.942-5.523h-1.73v-.766c.48.035 2.238.035 2.84.035.73 0 2.398 0 3.039-.035v.766H28.16l2.645 3.695 2.593-3.48a5.147 5.147 0 0 0-1.617-.215v-.766c.446.035 1.989.035 2.543.035.5 0 1.914 0 2.324-.035v.766h-.46a6.25 6.25 0 0 0-1.047.054c-.586.051-.657.086-.836.32l-3 4.012 4.492 6.262H37.5v.766c-.445-.032-2.273-.032-2.84-.032Zm0 0"
          style={{
            stroke: "none",
            fillRule: "nonzero",
            fill: "#000",
            fillOpacity: 1,
          }}
        />
      </svg>
    </div >
  );
};

export default TEXSymbol;
```

I then call this in the `App.tsx` file:

```js
import Note from "../components/common/Note";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const noteData = [
    { name: "Lec 1", tex_path: "/home/fff/", pdf_path: "/home/fff/", tex: true, pdf: false },
    { name: "Lec 2", tex_path: "/home/fff/", pdf_path: "/home/fff/", tex: true, pdf: true },
    { name: "Lec 3", tex_path: "/home/fff/", pdf_path: "/home/fff/", tex: false, pdf: true },
    { name: "Lec 4", tex_path: "/home/fff/", pdf_path: "/home/fff/", tex: false, pdf: false },
  ];

  return (
    <Note data={noteData} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can find all the code [here](https://github.com/SingularisArt/notes-manager/).

Comment: I don't think you can run a bash command from Electron/React without some kind wizardry. See this article which might help https://whoisryosuke.com/blog/2022/using-nodejs-apis-in-electron-with-react/

Comment: In this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10wGMzYgnqM&ab_channel=GillesCastel the guy made an app with electron and react and he made it when you click a button, it'll add a pdf to a filesystem or something. How did he do that?

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-internals-using-node-as-a-library might help

Comment: However keep in mind if you are making a portable app (which is the point with electron) bash may not be available.

Comment: @apokryfos I'm not making a portable app. It's just a desktop application for personal use.

Answer (score 0):

as this remains unanswered, but I had to dug into same. The way is to setup messaging between `electron` itself which has access to node and the frontend which is `React` in my case.

Material below is fully based on https://whoisryosuke.com/blog/2022/using-nodejs-apis-in-electron-with-react#why-do-all-this-work which I confirm is fully working as of posting date.

**./main.ts:** First we create new handler and add preload config option into electron launchfile:

```
new BrowserWindow({
    ...
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

...

ipcMain.handle("blender:version", async (_, args) => {
  console.log("running cli", _, args);
  let result;
  if (args) {//pay attention to this IF when debugging
    const blenderExecutable = checkMacBlender(args);
    // If MacOS, we need to change path to make executable
    const checkVersionCommand = `${blenderExecutable} -v`;

    result = execSync(checkVersionCommand).toString();
  }
  return result;
});
```

**./preload.js:** Extending global electron object with new method that will communicate to the backend:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  blenderVersion: async (blenderPath) =>
    ipcRenderer.invoke('blender:version', blenderPath),
  },
});
```

**./src/app.tsx:** Use in any react file:

```
const getVersion = async (blenderFile: string): Promise<VersionData> => {
  // Use IPC API to query Electron's main thread and run this method
  const result = await window.electron.blenderVersion(blenderFile)
}
```

**Typescript:** add e.g. `/types/index.d.ts` which will provide typing for your method in `preload.js`

```
import { DialogFileData } from './types';

declare global {
  /**
   * We define all IPC APIs here to give devs auto-complete
   * use window.electron anywhere in app
   * Also note the capital "Window" here
   */
  interface Window {
    electron: {
      showDialog: () => Promise<DialogFileData>;
      blenderVersion: (blenderFile: string) => Promise<string>;

            // Add any additional "APIs" here

    };
  }
}
```